# The instance of entity type 'BookLoan' cannot be tracked

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity

I'm trying to update an entity and I've run into the following error:

> InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'BookLoan'
>   cannot be tracked because another instance of this type with the same
>   key is already being tracked. When adding new entities, for most key
>   types a unique temporary key value will be created if no key is set
>   (i.e. if the key property is assigned the default value for its type).
>   If you are explicitly setting key values for new entities, ensure they
>   do not collide with existing entities or temporary values generated
>   for other new entities. When attaching existing entities, ensure that
>   only one entity instance with a given key value is attached to the
>   context.

I've done a little research and from what I can tell I'm apparently trying to track an already tracked entity when I use `_context.Update(bookloan);` but I'm not really sure what to do.

What I'm trying to do is update an existing entity/record in my database. Here are the get and post controllers as I'm not sure what else to share.

Get

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Return(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (isBookCheckedOut(id) == false)
        {
            //Not checked out
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            var bookloan = (from book in _context.Books.Where(b => b.BookId == id)
                        join loan in _context.BookLoans.Where(x => !x.ReturnedOn.HasValue) on book.BookId equals loan.BookID into result
                        from loanWithDefault in result.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        select new BookReturnViewModel
                        {
                            BookLoanID = loanWithDefault.BookLoanID,
                            BookID = book.BookId,
                            Title = book.Title,
                            StudentID = loanWithDefault == null ? null : loanWithDefault.StudentID,
                            StudentFristName = loanWithDefault == null ? null : loanWithDefault.Student.FirstName,
                            StudentLastName = loanWithDefault == null ? null : loanWithDefault.Student.LastName,
                            //Fines
                            CheckedOutOn = loanWithDefault == null ? (DateTime?)null : loanWithDefault.CheckedOutOn,
                            IsAvailable = loanWithDefault == null,
                            AvailableOn = loanWithDefault == null ? (DateTime?)null : loanWithDefault.DueOn
                        }).FirstOrDefault();

            if (bookloan == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(bookloan);
        }
    }
```

Post:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Return(BookReturnViewModel model)
    {


        if (ModelState.IsValid && isBookCheckedOut(1) == true)
        {
            var bookloan = new BookLoan()
            {
                BookLoanID = model.BookLoanID,
                BookID = model.BookID,
                StudentID = model.StudentID,
                CheckedOutOn = (DateTime)model.CheckedOutOn,
                DueOn = (DateTime)model.AvailableOn,
                ReturnedOn = DateTime.Now
            };


            try
            {

                _context.Update(bookloan);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {

            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {

        }

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Instead or 'creating' a new `BookLoan`, get the existing entity from the database based on the ID (e.g. `BookLoan data = db.BookLoans.Where(x => x.BookLoanID == model.BookLoanID).FirstOrDefault();`) and update its properties based on the view model and then save it.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly! I'd mark that as the answer but I don't think I can do that for comments. The way I was trying to do it was just me mimicking what I've seen Entity do when an edit with scaffolding is made.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your context already includes the entity, so rather that creating a new one, get the existing one based on the ID of the entity and update its properties, then save it

```
if (ModelState.IsValid && isBookCheckedOut(1) == true)
{
    // Get the existing entity
    BookLoan bookLoan = db.BookLoans.Where(x => x.BookLoanID == model.BookLoanID).FirstOrDefault();
    if (bookLoan != null)
    {
        bookLoan.BookID = model.BookID;
        bookLoan.StudentID = model.StudentID;
        .... // update other properties as required
        _context.Update(bookloan);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    ....
```

Side note: when returning the view, its good practice to pass back the model using `return View(model);` - your form controls will be correctly populated even if you don't (because they take the values from `ModelState`), but if you have any references to the model properties (e.g. `<div>@Model.someProperty</div>`) it would throw an exception.

Comment: It would *potentially* be faster to do db.BookLoans.Find(model.BookLoanID) because it will try to retrieve it from the context first before going to the db

Comment: how do you do it without a bunch of `existingObject.Property1 = updatedObject.Property1` stuff?